# Do you flip the inequality sign if multiplying a quadratic equation by $-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$(-1)(-x^{ 2 }+3x+18)<0(-1)$$

becomes

$$x^{ 2 }-3x-18>0\quad ?$$

I want to confirm before proceeding in solving a quadratic inequality.

Comment: HINT: -2 < -1. Multiply both sides by -1 to get 2 > 1

Comment: another way of saying "flip the inequality sign" is "change the sense of the inequality"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You flip sign if you multiply any inequality $A<B$ by a negative value $k<0$.

It becomes: $kA>kB$, or here $-A>-B$.

Alternatively, you can view this as pushing each term on the other side, thus also changing sign: it's like adding $-A$ then $-B$ to your inequality.

Comment: Because a lesser negative quantity is greater in value than a great negative quantity? 

$$-2 < -1$$ Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer It's another way to view this, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You flip the direction of the inequality, as you did, and that is true for any inequality, not just one or two degree polynomials.

$$f(x) < g(x) \iff -f(x) > -g(x)$$

---

Now, back to your inequality:  Correctly, you have $x^2 - 3x -18 = (x-6)(x+3) > 0$

Both factors must be positive, or both negative, for the inequality to hold.

$(x-6) > 0$ and $x+3>0 \implies x > 6$.

$x-6 < 0$ and $x + 3<0 \implies x<-3$.

So the answer is $x<-3$ or $x > 6$.

Comment: Before you edited, you got the reward of the shortest answer ! At the next opportunity, I shall answer $No$ to win against you. I am afraid that this could have be the only way for me to be better than you.

Comment: I just figured out how to solve quadratic inequalities. I was just wondering about what multiplying the inequality by a negative quantity would do to it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Hint [at WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-x%5E2%2B3x%2B18%3C0).